# How the javascript method "call" works in this code

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

Hey guys I'm studying for the Microsoft certification exam 40-780 and in the book

> Training Guide:Programming in HTML5 with Javascript and CSS3

they show an example on how to implement Inheritance in Javascript. And I need an addictional explanation on this line of code:

```
parent.call(this, year, make, model);
```

How this method "call" actually works in the context of the code.
Here's the code example by the book I've mentioned above.

```
var Vehicle = (function () {
    function Vehicle(year, make, model) {
        this.year = year;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
    }
    Vehicle.prototype.getInfo = function () {
        return this.year + ' ' + this.make + ' ' + this.model;
    };
    Vehicle.prototype.startEngine = function () {
        return 'Vroom';
    };

    return Vehicle;
})();

var Car = (function (parent) {
    function Car(year, make, model) {
        parent.call(this, year, make, model); // <-- how this works?
        this.wheelQuantity = 4;
    }
    return Car;
})(Vehicle);
```

Comment: `call()` allows you to set the context of the function call to something other than the calling object. Here `.call(this...`, `this` refers to `Car` not to `Vehicle` even though `parent` is a `Vehicle`. It is the line that creates the inheritance relationship. It gives all of the properties and prototypes of `Vehicle` to `Car`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Car class extending Vehicle class and all "this."s in Vehicle becomes Car instance. So if you contruct a new Car object, result becomes like this,

```
var c = new Car(2020,"EU","GSX");
Car {year: 2020, make: "EU", model: "GSX", wheelQuantity: 4}
```

There is explanation for call method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: Your answer and the article from mozilla was very helpful. Thank for the support.